# Django DeleteView select Database to use

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'll delete an object from my second unmanaged database (pgsql).

**view.py**

```
class DeleteDomain(DeleteView):
    model = Domains
    template_name = 'domain/delete_domain.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(DeleteDomain, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(DeleteDomain, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        if obj.created_by != self.request.user:
            raise Http404
        return obj

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('overview')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DeleteDomain, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['nav_overview'] = True
        return context
```

**settings.py:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'pgsql': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
        'USER': 'vmailuser',
        'NAME': 'virtualmail',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=public'
        },
    }
}
```

**models.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class Domains(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,
                          unique=True)
    domain = (
        models.CharField(max_length=255,
                         blank=False,
                         null=True,
                         validators=[RegexValidator(
                             regex=r"([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9-_]
                                     {2,}",
                             message=_("Invalid domain name")
                         )],
                         help_text=_('Please enter the email Domain 
                                     here')    
                         )
    )
    created_by = (
        models.CharField(max_length=255)
    )

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'domains'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.domain
```

**urls.py:**
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import AddDomainView, DeleteDomain


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'add', AddDomainView.as_view(), name='add_domain'),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', DeleteDomain.as_view(), 
           name='delete_domain'),
```

If I try to access https://localhost:8080/1/delete

I get:

```
Exception Value:    
no such table: domains
```

And in my Consolelog:

```
Internal Server Error: /domain/12/delete/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: domains

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/django/vmailpostfix/vmail/domain/views.py", line 59, in dispatch
    return super(DeleteDomain, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 115, in get
    self.object = self.get_object()
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/django/vmailpostfix/vmail/domain/views.py", line 62, in get_object
    obj = super(DeleteDomain, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 53, in get_object
    obj = queryset.get()
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 374, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 894, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 884, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/smindorf/PycharmProjects/venv/django/vmailpostfix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: domains
```

How can I select my pgsql-Database in my view?
I've no idea how to access my database her in my view.

Thanks

**update 1:**

In this view I can access:

```
  class AddDomainView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'domain/add_domain.html'
    model = Domains
    form_class = CreateDomainForm

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AddDomainView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_form(self, form_class=form_class):
        form = super(AddDomainView, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['domain'].queryset = Domains.objects.using('pgsql').all()
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        try:
            socket.gethostbyname(self.object.domain)
        except socket.gaierror:
            success, level, msg = False, messages.ERROR, _('Base domain does not exist.')
        else:
            try:
                self.object.created_by = self.request.user
                self.object.save(using='pgsql')
                success, level, msg = True, messages.SUCCESS, _('Domain added.')
            except IntegrityError:
                success, level, msg = False, messages.WARNING, _('Domain already exists .')
        messages.add_message(self.request, level, msg)
        url = reverse('overview')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

**update 2:**

my database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE domains (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    domain character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    created_by character varying
);
```

Comment: Have you run migrations to deploy the table to a database?

Comment: yes I've but the same error because I want to access the postgresql Databse not the sqlite3.

Comment: Set correct  postgresql credentials in settings.py.  You don’t need to set access in view, but in settings only.

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky the credentials are right, because I can access the Database in my other view. see edit.

Comment: How do you access it in another view?

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky see update 1 above

Comment: Could you put the whole code somewhere? Gist or github private repo? Looks where’re some strange things with a config

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky uploaded it to gitlab and added you. Settings.py in snippets

Comment: Strange things: models crated with `Meta: managed=False` so Django doesn't manage tables. There're different table names In `vmail/main/models.py` and `migrations`. In `settings.py`   default database is SQLite - I recommend remove it at all from there. Possibly due to some miscombination tables where added in different places. Try to drop sqlite from settings, make postgresql default, drop all the tables and recreate from scratch.

Comment: the strange thing is, that the sqlite3 database is only for django and it should't have other tables inside. And I'll use postres for postfix settings.
So when I move everything to postgres with different schema how can I access the other schema in  the views?
For example:
Schema 1: Postfix (virtualmail)
Schema 2: Django (django)
If I don't use classes I can access all different databases when I use `using`.

Comment: What if to put into one schema with prefixes as Django dies by default?

Comment: I'll try
Thanks a lot for your help